# Divide df columns by same column in R, but maintain df.column.names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame, which represents all municipalities and party positions

```
head(filtered_df,30)
              V1   V2
1         ABATIÁ  PDT
2         ABATIÁ  PSD
3         ABATIÁ  PHS
4         ABATIÁ   PP
...
9         ABATIÁ   PP
10        ABATIÁ PROS
11  ADRIANÓPOLIS  PSC
12  ADRIANÓPOLIS   PT
13  ADRIANÓPOLIS   PT
...
19  ADRIANÓPOLIS  PSC
20  ADRIANÓPOLIS  PSD
21 AGUDOS DO SUL PMDB
22 AGUDOS DO SUL PSDB
...
29 AGUDOS DO SUL  PSD
30 AGUDOS DO SUL PMDB
```

then,

```
freq_partidos<- table(data_filtrado)
freq_municipio <- table(data_filtrado$V1)


> str(freq_partidos)
 'table' int [1:399, 1:30] 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 2 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ V1: chr [1:399] "ABATIÁ" "ADRIANÓPOLIS" "AGUDOS DO SUL" "ALMIRANTE TAMANDARÉ" ...
  ..$ V2: chr [1:30] "DEM" "PC do B" "PDT" "PEN" ...
> str(freq_municipio)
 'table' int [1:399(1d)] 10 10 10 16 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:399] "ABATIÁ" "ADRIANÓPOLIS" "AGUDOS DO SUL" "ALMIRANTE TAMANDARÉ" ...
```

Here some show

```
> head(freq_partidos)
                     V2
V1                    DEM PC do B PDT PEN PHS PMB PMDB PMN PP PPL PPS PR PRB PROS PRP PRTB PSB PSC
  ABATIÁ                1       0   2   0   1   0    1   0  2   0   0  0   0    1   0    0   0   0
  ADRIANÓPOLIS          0       0   1   0   0   0    0   0  0   0   0  0   0    0   0    0   0   5
  AGUDOS DO SUL         0       0   0   0   0   0    3   0  3   0   0  0   0    0   0    0   2   0
  ALMIRANTE TAMANDARÉ   1       0   0   1   1   1    1   0  1   0   0  0   2    1   0    0   1   0
  ALTAMIRA DO PARANÁ    1       0   0   1   0   0    0   0  1   0   2  0   0    0   0    0   2   0
  ALTO PARAÍSO          0       0   1   0   0   0    0   0  3   0   1  0   0    0   0    0   0   0
                     V2
> head(freq_municipio)

             ABATIÁ        ADRIANÓPOLIS       AGUDOS DO SUL ALMIRANTE TAMANDARÉ  ALTAMIRA DO PARANÁ 
                 10                  10                  10                  16                  10 
       ALTO PARAÍSO 
                 10
```

I need to divide each column from `freq_partidos` by `freq_municípios`, but I need to know what is each column, so, must bring the "`freq_partidos`" col.names to my new df.

I`m looking for a final result like this:

```
                 DEM     PCdoB      PDT     PEN     PHS
ABATIÁ          1/10         0     2/10       0    1/10  
ADRIAN.            0         0     1/10       0       0
```

How is the better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but I will use that data for future info, so I can`t replace them

Comment: Got that. was much more easier than necessary. Just add <- on your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in `tidyverse`.  Grouped by 'V1', create a frequency column 'n', then groupedd by 'V2' and 'n' along with 'V1', get the frequency again ('n1'), divide the 'n1' by 'n' after `ungroup`ing, and then convert the 'long' format to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` (if needed, the 'V1' column can be converted to row names with `%>% tibble::column_to_rownames('V1')`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data_filtrado %>%
      group_by(V1) %>%
      mutate(n = n()) %>%
      group_by(V2, n, add = TRUE) %>%
      summarise(n1 = n()) %>%
      ungroup %>%
      mutate(prop = n1/n) %>%
      select(-n, -n1) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = V2, values_from = prop, 
              values_fill = list(prop = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 10
#  V1              PDT   PHS    PP  PROS   PSD   PSC    PT  PMDB  PSDB
#  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 ABATIÁ        0.167 0.167 0.333 0.167 0.167   0     0     0    0   
#2 ADRIANÓPOLIS  0     0     0     0     0.2     0.4   0.4   0    0   
#3 AGUDOS DO SUL 0     0     0     0     0.25    0     0     0.5  0.25
```

#### Update

Using the OP's data, the output is

```
# A tibble: 399 x 31
#   V1       DEM   PDT    PHS   PMDB     PP   PROS   PSD   PTB   PSC    PT     SD    PSB   PSDB    PEN    PMB   PRB
#   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 ABAT… 0.1      0.2 0.1    0.1    0.2    0.1    0.1     0.1   0     0   0      0      0      0      0      0    
# 2 ADRI… 0        0.1 0      0      0      0      0.1     0     0.5   0.2 0.1    0      0      0      0      0    
# 3 AGUD… 0        0   0      0.3    0.3    0      0.1     0     0     0   0      0.2    0.1    0      0      0    
# 4 ALMI… 0.0625   0   0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.125   0     0     0   0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.0625 0.125
# 5 ALTA… 0.1      0   0      0      0.1    0      0       0     0     0.1 0.1    0.2    0.1    0.1    0      0    
# 6 ALTO… 0        0.1 0      0      0.3    0      0.1     0     0     0.1 0      0      0.1    0      0      0    
# 7 ALTO… 0.1      0.1 0      0.1    0      0      0       0.1   0     0.1 0      0      0.2    0      0      0    
# 8 ALTO… 0        0   0      0      0.1    0      0.1     0.1   0     0   0      0.1    0.1    0      0      0    
# 9 ALTÔ… 0.2      0.2 0.1    0      0.1    0      0.1     0     0     0   0      0.2    0.1    0      0      0    
#10 ALVO… 0.1      0.2 0      0.3    0.1    0      0       0     0.1   0   0      0      0.1    0      0      0    
# … with 389 more rows, and 14 more variables: PSL <dbl>, PV <dbl>, PPS <dbl>, PR <dbl>, PTN <dbl>, PMN <dbl>,
#   PPL <dbl>, REDE <dbl>, PSDC <dbl>, PRP <dbl>, PRTB <dbl>, PTC <dbl>, `PT do B` <dbl>, `PC do B` <dbl>
```

---

Or using `base R`,  from OP's code, replicate the 'freq_municipio' to make the lengths same and do the division

```
dfnew <- freq_partidos/as.vector(freq_municipio[row(freq_partidos)])



df_new
#        V2
#V1                    PDT       PHS      PMDB        PP      PROS       PSC       PSD      PSDB        PT
#  ABATIÁ        0.1666667 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.0000000
#  ADRIANÓPOLIS  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.4000000 0.2000000 0.0000000 0.4000000
#  AGUDOS DO SUL 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2500000 0.2500000 0.0000000
```

#### Update

Using the OP's data

```
dfnew[1:3, 1:5]
#               V2
#V1              DEM PC do B PDT PEN PHS
#  ABATIÁ        0.1     0.0 0.2 0.0 0.1
#  ADRIANÓPOLIS  0.0     0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0
#  AGUDOS DO SUL 0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

#### data

```
data_filtrado <- structure(list(V1 = c("ABATIÁ", "ABATIÁ", "ABATIÁ", "ABATIÁ", 
"ABATIÁ", "ABATIÁ", "ADRIANÓPOLIS", "ADRIANÓPOLIS", "ADRIANÓPOLIS", 
"ADRIANÓPOLIS", "ADRIANÓPOLIS", "AGUDOS DO SUL", "AGUDOS DO SUL", 
"AGUDOS DO SUL", "AGUDOS DO SUL"), V2 = c("PDT", "PSD", "PHS", 
"PP", "PP", "PROS", "PSC", "PT", "PT", "PSC", "PSD", "PMDB", 
"PSDB", "PSD", "PMDB")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "29", "30"))
freq_partidos<- table(data_filtrado)
freq_municipio <- table(data_filtrado$V1)
```

Comment: I'm looking to the results, it didn`t work properly.
Take a look: https://imgur.com/zkIGqNv and https://imgur.com/7wfdMeb

ABATIA divider is 10

Comment: @AdilsonVCasula can you clarify with more details

Comment: PDT has a sum of 2, and when divided by 10 is giving NA

Comment: @AdilsonVCasula not able to reproduce with the data I updated

Comment: @AdilsonVCasula I. showed a reproducible example with `dput`. You can check my output

Comment: Yes. On your dput example it fits perfectly. But on my data is not fitting

Comment: @AdilsonVCasula the way to crosscheck is if you can `dput` either the tables or the initial data so that we can know the structure

Comment: Got the result just working with a single df.
*df_partidos$sum <- rowSums(df_partidos)* , then, *df_particip <- df_partidos/df_partidos$sum*

Comment: @AdilsonVCasula is this the `data_filtrado`

Comment: @AdilsonVCasula not able to get the `NA`.  can you test with the code again

Comment: Don't need it anymore. As iIsaid, I used your Base solution and managed my data into a single data.frame. Then, I did all the division there. Thank you very  much for helping

Comment: @AdilsonVCasula i think i changed the rep earlier to `row` `freq_partidos/as.vector(freq_municipio[row(freq_partidos)])`